# Can the 4th Gen iPod Touch really hold more songs with the same amount of internal memory?

Tags: ipod-touch, music, disk-space

I was price shopping for an iPod Touch and I came across this on eBay:

[image: The image shows all four generations of iPod Touch with 8GB storage, the first three generations hold 1750 songs, while it shows the 4th gen with the ability to hold 7000.]

All four generations are shown with 8GB of storage.  The number of songs each can hold is shown as 1750, except the 4th gen.  It shows 7000 songs.

Is there any truth to this chart, or did eBay just goof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BestBuy says 1750 ([Best Buy 4th Gen iPod Touch](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Apple®---iPod-touch®-8GB%2a-MP3-Player-%284th-Generation---Latest-Model%29---Black/9225377.p?id=1218062715447&skuId=9225377)), so I think eBay just goofed.

According to this answer ([Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101212192625AA1wnba)), the 8GB holds 1750. What's interesting is that, according to the Yahoo answer, the 32GB version stores 7000 songs, and it would make sense if eBay just got the two confused.